# How is the next retry time calculated for durable functions when there is a backoffCoefficient set?

Tags: azure-durable-functions

If my activity function fails I want it to be automatically retried. I want it to first retry first after a few seconds and then repeatedly. The last attempt should be after about 4 days. The initially retries should be seconds apart and then the frequency should back off so that at the end it is trying every 4 hours or so. How should the parameters of the RetryOptions be set to accomplish this? I.e. what is the formula to calculate the sequence of retry times given the following parameters:

```
firstRetryIntervalInMilliseconds = 3000
maxNumberOfAttempts  = 100
backoffCoefficient  = 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CallActivityWithRetry uses an [exponential backoff mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) to calculate retry intervals. ([source code](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/blob/61a2dc2f94cfa0aa2aae6ceb080717bad8a616b8/src/DurableTask.Core/RetryInterceptor.cs#L81)) The nth retry's delay is calculated by this formula:

`firstRetryIntervalInMilliseconds * backoffCoefficient ^ n`

The [RetryOptions](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/blob/azure-storage/src/DurableTask.Core/RetryOptions.cs) class has many configurable properties, including `MaxRetryInterval` and `RetryTimeout`, that should help achieve your desired retry behavior.